# jQuery need refresh to get the html()

Tags: jquery

I automatically generate input tag on each  link within the form make the .html() from the link become input val().
The text that I want to get is inside a < strong > tag this is why I use .children() function.

The problem is that this code need a page refresh to work properly. However var htmltoval return 'undefined' I try to put this loop before, after, on $(document).ready etc...

I guess it's because the elements was dynamically added.

Here is the code:

```
var content_input = '<input class="btn_menu_search" type="radio"/>';
$('form#form_search a').after(content_input);

$('#form_search :input').each(function () {
    var htmltoval = $(this).prev('a').children().html().toLowerCase();
    console.log(htmltoval) // return undefined on first page load 
    // however return the inner html string as expected
    var htmltoval = htmltoval.split(' ').join('');
    $(this).val(htmltoval);
});
```

Any ideas?

Update here the html:

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="form_search">
                    <h4 class="title"><span><strong>Villes</strong></span></h4>

                        <ul class="list-arrow" id="bienes">
                            <li><a class="bienes"><strong>Paris</strong></a></li>
                            <li><a class="bienes"><strong>Londres</strong></a> </li>
                            <li><a class="bienes"><strong>Tokyo</strong></a></li>
                            <li><a class="bienes"><strong>Moscou</strong></a></li>
                            <li><a class="bienes"><strong>Rio de Janeiro</strong></a></li>
                        </ul>

 <!-- etc-->
</form>
```

Edit: The page work fine after the page refresh even after clear cache. The bug is only on first browser load.

Comment: can you share the html for `form#form_search`

Comment: make sure your code is inside a $(function(){}); wrapper, maybe it's running before the document is actually ready (hence undefined html)?

Comment: Thks. I try all of this. Even try to add a delay setTimeout() inside a $(document).ready() to be sure this code we be the last to fired... Still not work

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle.net for the code?

Comment: Hi Sam. Never use this allready. I will try. thks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's going to change something but I added a semicolon to this line `console.log(htmltoval)` and i put the declaration of `htmltoval` outside of the `each` loop. I also changed the looping element by using the class instead:

```
var content_input = '<input class="btn_menu_search" type="radio"/>';
$('form#form_search a').after(content_input);

var htmltoval = "";
$('.btn_menu_search').each(function () {
    htmltoval = $(this).prev('a').children().html().toLowerCase();
    console.log(htmltoval); // return undefined on first page load 
    // however return the inner html string as expected
    htmltoval = htmltoval.split(' ').join('');
    $(this).val(htmltoval);
});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VtAjA/10/)

Comment: thks but definitively not work to me TypeError: $(...).prev(...).children(...).html(...) is undefined

Comment: Are you sure you do the editing correctly? There is no reason to get this error!

Comment: I guess that, the fact that everything work fine after the first page load mean that my code is well edited. After new test i saw jquery can grab input element newly added and add value to it. It even can grab my .html() by refered to the input id (id generated too) if I place my <a> out of the <ul> <li> element. So my test tend to prouve that all element could be acces...I mean that inside each() function $(this).prev('a').children().html() dont work when the same element can be acces by this code $('#inputID').prev('a').children().html() when it outside <ul> <li> o_0

Comment: Have you tried to loop on something else, like `$('.btn_menu_search').each(function () {`?

Comment: Man believe it or not I lost two days on this issue. But finally you got it. Just call the class work fine :) pfffffffiiiu  thks a lot Fabien.

Comment: Perfect! :) I know what it is :) I will update my answer to take this in consideration, in case this could help someone else.